# Create a new vector with no element being in the same position as the original vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `V1` (with two or more elements):

```
V1 <- 1:10
```

I can reorder the original vector with the function `sample`.  This function, however, cannot make sure that none element in the new vector being in the same position as the original vector. For example:

```
set.seed(4)
V2 <- sample(V1)
```

This will result in a vector that has two elements being in the same position as the original one:

```
V1[V1 == V2]

3 5
```

My question is: Is it possible to generate a random vector to make sure that no element being in the same position between the two vectors?

Comment: Your requirement of all elements shifting from their original positions means that you _don't_ want a pure random ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement of not having certain indices in the vector not being able to shift means that you don't want a purely random permutation, where that might happen.  The best I could come up with is to just loop, using `sample` until we find a vector where every element shifts:

```
v1 <- 1:10
v1_perm <- v1
cnt <- 0

while (sum(v1 == v1_perm) > 0) {
    v1_perm <- sample(v1)
    cnt <- cnt + 1
}

v1
v1_perm
paste0("It took ", cnt, " tries to find a suitable vector")

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1]  3 10  4  7  8  1  6  2  5  9
[1] "It took 3 tries to find a suitable vector"
```

### Demo

Note that I have implemented the requirement of shifting positions with shifting values.  This of course isn't strictly true, because two values could be the same.  But, assuming all your entries are unique, then checking for zero overlap of values equates with zero overlap of indices.

Comment: Update: Is it possible to extend it to the situations where I intend to create two of more vectors where none duplicate values existing in the same position? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248550/create-new-vectors-with-no-element-being-in-the-same-position-as-the-original-ve