# Create new vectors with no element being in the same position as the original vector as well as with other vectors?

Tags: r

This question is an extension of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606467/create-a-new-vector-with-no-element-being-in-the-same-position-as-the-original-v/52606585?noredirect=1#comment104682820_52606585) I asked earlier.

Suppose I have a vector V1 (with two or more elements):

```
V1 <- 1:10
```

I want to sample one or several vectors that:

(1). no element is in the same position as the original vector.

(2). no element is in the same position among the new vectors.

The following two are such vectors:

```
9  4  7  1  2  5  3 10  6  8
5  7  4  2  3  8  9  6 10  1
```

Comment: You can easily extend the rejection sampling shown in the linked answer to more than one vector. It's not efficient but easy to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this :

```
#Define the vector
V1 <- 1:10
#Number of rows
n <- 7
#Create a matrix with the vector `V1` in each row
mat <- matrix(V1, ncol = length(V1), nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
i <- 2

while(i <= n) {
   #Get randomised V1
   temp <- sample(V1)
   #Check if any of the previous row does not have the same combination 
   if (all(colSums(t(t(mat) == temp)) == 0)) {
       #Add the random vector in the matrix
       mat[i, ] <- temp
       i <- i + 1
   }
}

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#[2,]    4    5    6    7   10    2    1    9    3     8
#[3,]    2    6    7    9    1    3    8   10    5     4
#[4,]    9    3    1    2    4    8    6    5   10     7
#[5,]    7    8    5    3    6    9   10    4    1     2
#[6,]    3    1    4    5    8   10    9    7    2     6
#[7,]    8    4    2   10    9    1    5    6    7     3
```